# Jpeg Image Classification

Tags: jpeg-2000, image-classification

I want to perform Image Classification(JPEG Image).
I loaded the image in QGIS.
Everytime i perform an action, i get a screen pop-up of Co-ordinate Reference System(CRS).
How should that be handled?

Secondly, i bypass CRS by selecting WGS84 and later when i am about to add the ROI , i receive the following error
**

*- *"AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'RasterCount'*

---

Comment: I'm not sure this will answer your question, but it seems to me that simply selecting a CRS won't give your .jpg file coordinates. Before trying to draw the ROIs, I'd suggest you first georreference your image. If you are not familiarized with the process there's a plugin called **SCP** with a lot of documentation online that can help you with it.